# Change your nickname command discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command that can change a user's nickname but I can’t make it work. I have tried to find solutions but I can't.

Here is my code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
      .setName("nickname")
      .setDescription("Change your nickname")
      .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName("nickname")
        .setDescription("New Nickname")
        .setRequired(true)
        ),

    async execute(interaction) {
      const { options } = interaction;
      const nick = options.getString("nickname");
      const member = interaction.author;
      
      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setDescription(`Succesfully changed your nickname to ${nick}`)
        .setColor(0xFFFFFE)
        .setTimestamp();

      await member.setNickname(`${nick}`)
        
      await interaction.reply({
        embeds: [embed],
        ephemeral: true
    
    });  
  }    
}
```

I think the problem is with this but I'm not sure

```js
await member.setNickname(`${nick}`)
```

Comment: Does the embed send successfully? Does the bot have permission to change user nicknames? Are any errors generated when this fails to run?

Comment: The bot has permissions the embed it doesn’t send it just say the application did not respond and the error i get is cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘setNickname’)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `interaction.author` is `undefined`. You probably thought that it's like `message.author` but that's still a `User`, not a `GuildMember` and only members have the `setNickname()` method.

You should get the member instead of the user though. Try something like this:

```js
const member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.user.id)
```

You could also use `options.getMember("nickname")` if you used `addUserOption()` instead of `addStringOption()`.

Comment: The problem i have is with ```await member.setNickname(`${nick}`)``` i know that because if i remove it everything works is there something i can do to fix it im also now to JavaScript

Comment: `member` is `undefined`, of course, there is a problem with `undefined.setNickname()`. Have you read my answer? Is there anything that's unclear?

Comment: I have change the ```const member = interaction.author``` with this ```const member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.user.id)```  from the code u gave me but still it doesn’t work

Comment: And what's the error message?

Comment: It says missing permissions but i have dabble check everything and i have permissions i dont know to do

Answer (score 0):

I was just making a similar command and ran into the same issue as you. I realized the member that I'm trying to change the nickname of, had another role assigned to them, which was higher than the role of the bot. Give this a look and let me know. Also, make sure you have `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds` and`GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers` passed in your intents.